# Is Stack Exchange a school/educator? Should SE be qualified/accredited as, and graded like, an academic institution/environment/school, legally?

Tags: discussion, legal, business-model, quality

Should Stack Exchange be considered like a school/academic environment (legally)? Would that qualify it a for-profit or non-profit university/school?

Would academic qualifications/standards help? There are clearly many people of good repute (and good reputation scores) who qualify their educational background as important (when grading people for moderation, for example). Is that a valid learning/teaching dynamic to qualify, according to the law as, some sort of teaching dynamic.

Is Stack Exchange a school or, as [Catija rephrased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stackexchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-accredited-as-and-gra#comment1201103_359915), are there "aspirations towards accreditation" as an educational institution of some kind?

As [Wizard reflected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stack-exchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-accredited-as-and-g#comment1201129_359918) on their [Accepted Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359918/163204), "the only relation is that both have students, teachers, and management, and they all take part in sharing knowledge. **Can you give more relations?**" ([Martin helped define a few missed relations.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stack-exchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-accredited-as-and-g#comment1201164_359918)) Please help us define/spreadsheet the (legal) relations between each.

Comment: "*Should Stackexchange.com be considered like a school/academic environment (legally)?*" according to which jurisdiction?

Comment: @VLAZ Well SE is American correct? And I am American (with birth certificate) as well. So is that the jurisdiction according to the definition?

Comment: There is a lot about you as a person that is in no way relevant to the question. Please clean it up.

Comment: @Luuklag Feel free to edit yourself if that is your judgement. I would not have asked the question if not for why and how I am asking the question. I only wrote 3 paragraphs total, 1 about my experience with SE/Quora as a School, feels relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you're being graded on your grammar - while people may edit your posts to have correct spelling or grammar, that doesn't mean you're being "graded" on it - we just expect posts here to be easily readable and incorrect spelling and poor grammar decreases readability. Having posts edited has absolutely nothing to do with being a school. Please update your question to focus on one question.

Comment: @Catija Am I allowed to request somebody edit to reflect their commented judgements? So others can read that is the reason, somebody else felt that made the question better. Even though there are certainly questions that drop a line about reasoning which pass.

Comment: This is your question - none of us here can understand what you're truly trying to ask, so if you want an answer to a question, we need a focused question that is supported by some amount of effort to explain yourself clearly. Since you're conflating two separate things, we can not focus on addressing your actual concern unless you clarify what you actually want to know - do you want to actually understand whether this platform has any aspirations towards accreditation or do you want to have a discussion about when editing is appropriate or the expectations for spelling/grammar in posts here?

Comment: There is only one thing I would like to say. SO is an encyclopedia, not a school.

Comment: @Catija Is it relevant to you now? Or should I just drop all "I" statements?

Comment: Your reaction to comments cannot be tolerated.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Sorry, it's stressful having people write several judgemental comments instantly while being heavily downvoted not upvoted here, for the record.

Comment: You can comment on my answer by clicking "add a comment".

Comment: I think @Catja read my question as reading "aspiring to accreditation" so I added that part, does it not help then? Maybe that should have just been their comment/answer maybe? (Replying to +new_QO https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stackexchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-as-and-graded-like-an/359917?noredirect=1#comment1201124_359917, sorry not sure to reply to +C or +n here.) ...oh and sorry +Catja I said "for you" I shoud have said"for us", trying to fit in the 5 minute comment edit period is stress

Comment: I don't see the inspiration for your question

Comment: I have been an educator, working in a school/academic environment. I'm also a moderator on Stack Overflow. I see no commonalities between the two, other than "people ask questions". Of course, that's also true of my current workplace, which is a for-profit technology company. So I really don't know what you see as the parallels. Everyone asks questions everywhere. That doesn't make it a school. I cannot understand what you are trying to say in your middle paragraph. I cannot determine how to parse it. All I can say is that we're not teachers, and we don't grade anyone.

Comment: @CodyGray There is a lot to read here, right before you came there was progress: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stack-exchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-accredited-as-and-g#comment1201166_359918 which I just Accepted because it understood the question. I realize my writing is not the best but that Answerer and the Commenter I mentioned there did a good/superb job at spreadsheeting the "Q&A relations to Education", & each of the individuals there appear to understand the spirit and letter of the question, however feel free to reword if it helps us.

Comment: The answer seems to say that there are no commonalities whatsoever. That you accepted that answer made it even more difficult for me to understand your question!

Comment: @CodyGray That is why I said "answerer" and "commenter" at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359915/is-stack-exchange-a-school-educator-should-se-be-qualified-accredited-as-and-g#comment1201166_359918, together they were able to define relations that are legally relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's keep it simple. In the below, Stack Exchange users who ask questions are school students, Stack Exchange users who answer questions are teachers, and Stack Exchange moderators/staff are the school principal and administrative staff.

| School | Stack Exchange |
| --- | --- |
| Teachers teach first, students ask questions later | Students ask first, teachers answer later |
| Fresh students are not expected to start with existing knowledge | Even fresh students must have prior knowledge |
| School manager and staff don't take active part in teaching | Manager and staff take active part in teaching |

Those are more than enough to conclude that Stack Exchange is very far from being a school/academic environment and will never be.

Comment: I wish that table was part of my question, I think that is what I was thinking about.

Comment: I agree it is sometimes far from a school, but I think it could sometimes be described as a school/educational. O:)

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Described as a school? Why? In what sense can it be described as a school?

Comment: @prosody the only relation is that both have students, teachers, and management, and they all take part in sharing knowledge. Can you give more relations?

Comment: At that point I think that is part of the q (I am curious, I do not know maybe, is that okay at this point? Or is me not going further going to ruin the question?), and maybe was thinking/hoping others might be able to help define how it relates to being a school. Otherwise I can try to reply myself but I am writing alot here and that does not always go well, being brief might help me greatly to be frank, I would rather turn the issue to others to explore. I mean an "Extended School/Q&A Table Version" (vs "Simple") could go towards addressing gaps between what defines/supports each system?

Comment: @prosody not sure what you mean, if you mean you want to post such a table but with more details then sure, by all means you have the right to post it as new answer.

Comment: I could try to integrate your "Simple School/Q&A Table" into the primary question, and ask others to help with an "Extended School/Q&A Table Version" (vs "Simple" put in the question) to go towards addressing gaps between what defines/supports each system? That would be another question, or good to integrate here? Your table is excellent for delineating to start. Otherwise keep the current dynamic, and then I might hope others reference your table, it might help? I mean are there multiple questions, accreditation, being like a school, how like a school? Given votes so far, biased towards 1 q.

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext you are understanding SO so wrong,

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget There is nothing right about comparing a Q&A site filled with academics with a school environment? Or mentioning Stackexchange/Quora advertises itself as a place to learn?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Again, you are understanding SO wrong.

Comment: You missed one: 'Teachers are paid a salary to compensate them for answering the same questions over, and over, again, even though a trivial Google gives the answer, SE contributors are unpaid volunteers who are sick of being asked to teach Computers 101'

Comment: Ooooh...another one: 'Students who persistently threaten and abuse teachers can be excluded from school.  SE users who threaten and abuse curators can likewise be excluded, but can trivially change their identities, re-enroll and continue the abuse'

Comment: and...... 'Students who claim discrimination on grounds of race/religion/sexuality can have their allegations investigated.  SE users can claim any feelings of victimhood they want and be believed without evidence'

Comment: I am accepting your answer, in great part/debt to @MartinJames helping define other relations (and realistically worried about the Extreme Voting disturbing/shutting the question before it will get appropriate responses). Thank each of you for really working to spreadsheet the differentials. I would be humbled if there was enouragement for Martin to either (A) Continue commenting with great examples. (B) Edit the/Shadow's answer with their entries or (C) Make their own answer (burrow and cite the table here) to go further.

Comment: @new QOpenGLWidget: Can you elaborate on *"understanding SO wrong"*? E.g., what in particular?

Answer (score 12):

**No.** SO is not meant to be a school, nor is it a school right now.

> There are clearly many people of good repute (and good reputation scores) who qualify their educational background as important (when grading people for moderation, for example)

There are two things wrong with this sentence. First of all, I don't see the connection between moderation and educational background. Second of all, moderation is not "grading" people. The main reason we edit posts and ask for clarity is because SO is meant to be an encyclopedia, where questions and answers are meant to help people.

For example, if a post has poor grammar, no one will be able to understand it. Hence, people improve grammar to help people understand.

And, if a question is confusing, we ask for clarity, because if the question is confusing, it is less likely to help people.

So, to answer your second question, no, moderation is not a "grading system".

Comment: Can we ask to focus on the title question and not me specifically? The school issue is why I bring myelf into the question, but it's a school/education question, I am not asking to talk about me (or how I am being graded specifically), I did not ask about me in the title.

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext My answer does not contain any details about you.

Comment: Edited https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/359915/4 to not be about grammar and be about accreditedness.

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext What *is* your question?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext also, you didn't mention accreditedness?

Comment: Good call, fixed, I cut the 3rd and 4th but only need to cut one, damn, the votes/instacomments are stress/pressure, and I need to do it all before it gets flagged and I can not edit again (all ten comments and 10 votes in under 1 hour so far), eek.